# What is the difference between operators "numpy.dot()", " * " and "@" when working on numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, operators

I want to solve equations x+6y−z=0, x+2y−2z=1, −5x+2z=8 using python.
I tried using different multiplication operations to multiply matrices and answer was different when different multiplication operations were used.I want to know the reason for this.

```
import numpy as np

a= np.array([[2,6,-1],[1,2,-2],[-5,0,2]])
b= np.array([0,1,8])
a_inv= np.linalg.inv(a)
#case1
c= np.dot(a_inv,b)
print(c.shape)
#case2
print((a_inv@b).shape)
#case3
print((a_inv*b).shape)
```

case1 and case2 give correct output but case3 doesn't.
Outputs:
case1:
(3,)
case2:
(3,)
case3:
(3, 3)

Comment: `@` was introduced in Python 3.5 because NumPy users were tired of writing out `np.matmul` (which is equivalent to `np.dot` in the case of 1xn/nx1 matrix multiplication).

Comment: `*` is elementwise multiplication (`.*` in MATLAB). `dot` is the standard matrix multiplication.  `@` uses `matmul`, a more recent version of matrix multiplication that handles 'batches' of  arrays better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` operator in numpy differs from matrix multiplication. When you do `a_inv * b` (in your case), you are creating a 3x3 array as follows:

```
[[a[0,0] * b[0], a[0,1] * b[0], a[0,2] * b[0]],
 [a[1,0] * b[1], a[1,1] * b[1] ...]] #etc.
```

Asides from `dot` you can do matrix multiplication with `np.matmul(a_inv, b)`, or you can explicitly tell numpy that your arrays are matrices by using `np.matrix`:

```
a_inv = np.matrix(a_inv)
b = np.matrix(b).T   # note that b will be a row vector, so you need to transpose it to make it a column vector
a_inv * b   #now numpy will interpret '*' as matrix multiplication
>>[[-2. ]
 [ 0.5]
 [-1. ]]
```